# Ansible / jmespath - 1d list to zipped list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

I'm attempting to transform a 1d list of AWS EC2 IDs into a list of dictionaries suitable for usage as the `targets` param to the Ansible [elb_target_group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/elb_target_group_module.html) module.

Sample input:

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "instance_ids": [
        "i-1111",
        "i-2222",
        "i-3333"
    ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "targets": [
        {"Id": "i-1111", "Port": 6443},
        {"Id": "i-2222", "Port": 6443},
        {"Id": "i-3333", "Port": 6443},
    ]
}
```

What I've tried: a `json_query` / JMESPath expression which confusingly returns `null` values:

```yaml
---

- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - i-1111
      - i-2222
      - i-3333
    keys_list:
      - Id
      - Port
  tasks:
    - debug: var=instance_ids
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ instance_ids | zip_longest([6443], fillvalue=6443) | list }}" # Halfway there...
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ instance_ids | zip_longest([6443], fillvalue=6443) | list | map('json_query', '{Id: [0], Port: [1]}') | list }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "i-1111",
            6443
        ],
        [
            "i-2222",
            6443
        ],
        [
            "i-3333",
            6443
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Port": null
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Port": null
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Port": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**How should I adjust the `'{Id: [0], Port: [1]}'` part ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled my way to a working solution with `json_query` and a JMESPath `int` literal:

```
"{{ instance_ids | json_query('[*].{Id: @, Port: `6443`}') }}"
```

Example:

```yaml
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - i-1111
      - i-2222
      - i-3333
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ instance_ids | json_query('[*].{Id: @, Port: `6443`}') }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "Id": "i-1111",
            "Port": 6443
        },
        {
            "Id": "i-2222",
            "Port": 6443
        },
        {
            "Id": "i-3333",
            "Port": 6443
        }
    ]
}
```